# MSYS2 (64 bit): The C compiler identification is unknown

Tags: makefile, cmake, msys2

I'm new to building in Windows. I'm building the following project: https://github.com/arkottke/strata.

The page suggests installing dependencies using MSYS2. I've installed MSYS2 and installed everything as instructed exactly, but I get the following when trying to build using cmake:

```
$ cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:31 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/isb17182/strata/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/isb17182/strata/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I've seen answers for the same problem on other building platforms, but these are too complicated for me to understand currently. If someone could provide a simple explanation of how to resolve this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As the project did not say to install a compiler and dev tools did you run `pacman -S base-devel gcc` ? If yes, what does `gcc --version` outputs?  See https://www.devdungeon.com/content/install-gcc-compiler-windows-msys2-cc for further instructions.

Comment: I just installed gcc. It is version 9.1.0. The installation seems to help, but now I'm confronted with an error saying I did not provide "FindQt5PrintSupport.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, even though I can find this file in the directory: "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\cmake\Qt5PrintSupport"?

Comment: Be sure you're using the `cmake` of msys2 (as the project build instructions suggest you should install), not a regular Windows `cmake` installed elsewhere on the system.

Comment: There are three MSYS2 shells, so which one did you start?  What do you see when you run the commands `echo $MSYSTEM` and `which gcc` and `which cmake`?

Comment: 'echo $MSYSTEM' returns 'MSYS'

'which gcc' returns '/usr/bin/gcc',

'which cmake' returns '/usr/bin/cmake',

Answer (score 2):

#### This is what worked for me

Thanks to everyone who contributed.
Run

`pacman -S base-devel gcc`

Which will update GCC to latest and verify by

`gcc --version`

Be sure you're using the cmake of msys2 (as the project build instructions suggest you should install), not a regular Windows cmake installed elsewhere on the system.

`which cmake`

After this ere execute your command...build done ;)

Comment: It's a bit strange to use `gcc` package. Normally you want either `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` or `mingw-w64-i686-gcc` (for 64 and 32 bits respectively), not the plain `gcc` which uses Cygwin. This is further confirmed by the library readme suggesting to install some libraries prefixed with `mingw-w64-x86_64-`.